# Decorators on classmethods

Tags: python, decorator, class-method

I have child classes which inherit some basic functionality from a parent class.
The child classes shall have a generic constructor `prepare_and_connect_constructor()` which does some magic around the object creation of the parent class.
For simplicity, the magic is done by a simple function based decorator (ultimately, it should be a part of the parent class).

```
def decorate_with_some_magic(func):
    def prepare_and_connect(*args, **kwargs):
        print("prepare something")
        print("create an object")
        obj = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print("connect obj to something")
        return obj

    return prepare_and_connect


class Parent:

    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.a}"


class Child(Parent):

    @classmethod
    @decorate_with_some_magic
    def prepare_and_connect_constructor(cls, a, b):
        """ use the generic connection decorator right on object creation """
        obj = super().__init__(a)
        # put some more specific attributes (over the parents class)
        obj.b = b
        return obj

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        """ init without connecting """
        super().__init__(a)
        self.b = b

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.a}, {self.b}"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(Child.prepare_and_connect_constructor("special child", "needs some help"))
```

Using this code i finally get

```
obj = super().__init__(a)
  TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'a'
```

when running `prepare_and_connect_constructor()`.

Actually I would expect that the `super.__init__(a)` call should be the same as in `Child.__init__`.
I guess the reason is related to the `classmethod` but I can't figure it out.

What's wrong with this call?

**Update**: In general what was wrong is that `__init__` doesn't return an object.

Due to the hints and thoughts from the answers i modified my code to achieve what i need:

```
class Parent:

    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    @staticmethod
    def decorate_with_some_magic(func):
        def prepare_and_connect(*args, **kwargs):
            print("prepare something")
            print("create an object")
            obj = func(*args, **kwargs)
            print("connect obj to something")
            return obj

        return prepare_and_connect

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.a}"


class ChildWithOneName(Parent):

    @classmethod
    @Parent.decorate_with_some_magic
    def prepare_and_connect_constructor(cls, a, b):
        """ use the generic connection decorator right on object creation """
        obj = super().__new__(cls)
        obj.__init__(a, b)
        print("Does the same as in it's __init__ method")
        return obj

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        """ init without connecting """
        super().__init__(a)
        self.b = b

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.a}, {self.b}"


class GodChild(Parent):

    @classmethod
    @Parent.decorate_with_some_magic
    def prepare_and_connect_constructor(cls, a, names):
        """ use the generic connection decorator right on object creation """
        obj = super().__new__(cls)
        obj.__init__(a, names)
        # perform some more specific operations
        obj.register_all_names(names)
        print("And does some more stuff than in it's __init__ method")
        return obj

    def __init__(self, a, already_verified_names):
        """ init without connecting """
        super().__init__(a)
        self.verified_names = already_verified_names

    def register_all_names(self, names=[]):
        self.verified_names = []

        def verify(text):
            return True

        for name in names:
            if verify(name):
                self.verified_names.append(name)


    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.a}, {self.verified_names}"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(ChildWithOneName.prepare_and_connect_constructor("special child", "needs some help"), end='\n\n')
    print(GodChild.prepare_and_connect_constructor("unknown child", "needs some verification"), end='\n\n')
    print(ChildWithOneName("my child", "is clean and doesn't need extra magic"))
```

- `decorate_with_some_magic` is now a part of the `Parent` class (using a staticmethod) as it is a related generic functionality
- Each child class (added one more for illustration) has it's own `prepare_and_connect_constructor` **classmethod**, which calls its own constructor and does optionally some additional work

Comment: `__init__` doesn't return anything, and since you are calling `super` from a class method, `super().__init__` requires an explicit instance as its first argument.

Comment: True, didn't think about this

Answer (score 1):

You have a slight misunderstanding of the magic methods `__init__` and `__new__`. `__new__` creates a new object, e.g. returns a instance of the class. `__init__` just modifies the object in place. So an easy fix for your problem would be de following:

```
@classmethod
@decorate_with_some_magic
def prepare_and_connect_constructor(cls, a, b):
    """ use the generic connection decorator right on object creation """
    obj = super().__new__(cls)
    obj.__init__(a)
    # put some more specific attributes (over the parents class)
    obj.b = b
    return obj
```

I however don't think you should use it like this. Instead, your probably should overwrite `__new__`

Comment: What should be the change to `__new__` to do it correctly?

Comment: @maggie That would assume you always want to connect. Is that the case?

Comment: No, 's not, that is why i am asking. It should be an alternative (to write less code). But it's not always the case.

Answer (score 1):

Decorators work on callables. Since there is no difference between calling a function and initiating a class, you can use your decorator directly on the class:

```
def decorate_with_some_magic(func):
    def prepare_and_connect(*args, **kwargs):
        print("prepare something")
        print("create an object")
        obj = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print("connect obj to something")
        return obj

    return prepare_and_connect


class Parent:

    @classmethod
    def prepare_and_connect_constructor(cls, a, b):
        return decorate_with_some_magic(cls)(a, b)

    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.a}"

class Child(Parent):

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        """ init without connecting """
        super().__init__(a)
        self.b = b


    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.a}, {self.b}"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    normal_child = Child("normal child", "no help needed")
    print(normal_child)
    special_child = Child.prepare_and_connect_constructor("special child", "needs some help")
    print(special_child)
```

Output:

```
normal child, no help needed
prepare something
create an object
connect obj to something
special child, needs some help
```

Comment: But i want to have a "normal" constructor and an alternative one. Thats not possible with that approach.

Comment: Use the decorator "outside" the class. See my  modified answer.

Comment: Ok, this works and looks nice, but for multiple child classes there are different ways on how these classes work. Its not guaranteed that the same stuff happens as it does in the normal constructor... Perhaps its not the best design which i am thinking of, but isn't it possible to do it with a class method?

Comment: Now with class method.